# чистый C: как правильно дождаться окончания работы двух потков?

Tags: c, многопоточность, pthread

пробую запускать некотрые вычисления в отдельных тредах, вызывая два (или более) раза подряд pthread_create():

Использую GNU-шный C - компилятор, OS - Ubuntu 20

```
    pthread_t thread, thread2;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, calc1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, calc2, NULL);
```

Потом мне надо дождаться окончания вычислений:

```
    pthread_join (thread, (void*) &calc1);
    pthread_join (thread2, (void*) &calc2);
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что даже если у меня один из потоков закончит работу раньше, чем другой, я всё равно буду ждать ровно столько, сколько работает ПЕРВЫЙ из опрашиваемых в pthread_join() потоков? И потом у меня просто мгновенно отработает вторая строчка, которая опрашивает состояние потка, который уже закончил работу?

Вопрос выглядит довольно простым, просто у меня появились сомнения, что я делаю правильно.

Comment: Похоже на правду. Вставьте поочередно слипы в один поток 5 секунд, во второй - 1 секунду и проверьте, что общее время ожидания составит 5 секунд

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После того как поток отработает, он будет ждать, пока для него позовут join. И да, сам join отработает "моментально" в таком случае.  Собственно документация об этом и говорит https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html

> If that thread has already terminated, then pthread_join() returns immediately.

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснение!

Comment: @KoVadim, поздравляю со 100К!

Comment: Спасибо, теперь к 1кк надо идти